# Android Out Of Memory Exception storing huge amount of bytes

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, arrays

I'm working on a painting app in android.
Currently i'm working on the undo function - my idea is to store the coordinates and colors of the pixels which are changed.

I'm working with the RGBs for performance issues - so they are stored in a byte array.

currentRGBPixelArray is the array which contains the old ARGB values.
updatedRGBPixelArray is the array which contains the new ARGB values.

If a value within always 3 fields is different I know that I have to store these values. This is done on an Integer, Byte[] pair, where the Integer is the index of the pixel in the RGBPixelArray.

But with this code I get a out of memory exception when storing huge amount of data (for example if the background or a huge area like the screen with 1920*1080 is changed, maybe multiple times).

Here is my code:

```
List<Pair<Integer, Byte[]>> changeTupelHolder = new ArrayList<>();
for (int index = 0; index < width; index += 4) 
{
     if (currentRGBPixelArray[index] != updatedRGBPixelArray[index] ||
         currentRGBPixelArray[index+1] != updatedRGBPixelArray[index+1] ||
         currentRGBPixelArray[index+2] != updatedRGBPixelArray[index+2]) 
     {
           Pair<Integer, Byte[]> changeTupel = 
               new Pair<>(index, 
                          new Byte[]{currentRGBPixelArray[index],
                                     currentRGBPixelArray[index+1],
                                     currentRGBPixelArray[index+2]});
           changeTupelHolder.add(changeTupel);
     }
}
```

Then the changeTupelHolder is again stored on a Stack and poped when undo is called.

What can I do to handle the out of memory exception?
Is storing the changeTupelHolder on the storage a good idea (performance?)?
If it is, how can I do it just when the app tends to get out of memory?

Or do you have a totally different idea for my problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you explain more at what point you should store a change? What circumstance will trigger your code?
Also, can you use something like SVG?

Comment: It's just a simple painting activity - if i draw a cirle, fill an area or whatever I want to store the old pixel.

Comment: if it's just a *simple painting activity* then you should be able to use vectors and store them in your stack as paths.

Answer (score 2):

This is horribly inefficient way of holding image data.  The correct way to hold image data is a byte array byte data[]=new byte[4*NUM_PIXELS].  Getting a color for a pixel would then be data[pixelnum*4+COLOR_INDEX] where color index is 0 for alpha, 1 for red, 2 for green, and 3 for blue.

The way you're doing it-  you're creating millions of small objects each with their own significant amount of overhead, all to store a single byte each.  This would kill a PC.  And mobile phones do *horribly* with allocations, the key to performant android code is to minimize the number of objects allocated.

I know the modern school of thought is not to think of performance until you know there's a problem, but there's a giant asterisk on that-  you still need to use common sense.  Common sense should tell you that 1 object per pixel is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm not sure if you got me right. I have the image stored in currentRGBPixelArray which is byte[4*NUM_PIXELS], updatedRGBPixelArray is just temporary and just the changes are stored as Pairs because in most cases just maybe 2.000 out of the 2.000.000 pixels are changed, for example if you just paint a circle or a line.

Comment: Allocating even 2000 objects-  not counting the smaller objects that list will allocate internally-  is a huge amount and should never be done.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with vectors.

Actually I've done something similar to undo/redo with vectors and never ran into Out of Memory Exception.

I used [android.graphics.Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) and [android.graphics.Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) to create a vector object.

Here is sample code to convert a SVG to path and paint:

```
public VectorPathObject(final List<List<Object>> actions, final float left, final float top, final String color, final float strokeWidth) {
    mPath = new Path();
    for (List<Object> action : actions) {
        switch (action.get(0).toString()) {
            case M:
                mPath.moveTo(left + Float.parseFloat(action.get(1).toString()), top + Float.parseFloat(action.get(2).toString()));
                break;
            case Q:
                mPath.quadTo(left + Float.parseFloat(action.get(1).toString()), top + Float.parseFloat(action.get(2).toString()), left + Float.parseFloat(action.get(3).toString()), top + Float.parseFloat(action.get(4).toString()));
                break;
            case L:
                mPath.lineTo(left + Float.parseFloat(action.get(1).toString()), top + Float.parseFloat(action.get(2).toString()));
                break;
        }
    }
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setStyle(this.paintStyle);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(this.lineCap);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    mPaint.setAlpha(this.opacity);
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but I do have a filling tool which fills all kind of forms and i can't image a way to handle this with this method.